# cURL command executes in groovy script, but not when imported into a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to import a groovy script that executes a cURL command into my Jenkins pipeline. The cURL command executes properly when executing the groovy script outside of the pipeline (from the shell for example), but when inside the pipeline, my pipeline executes without errors, but the cURL command does not seem to have executed.

test.groovy:

```
  class GroovyClass{

   def executeCurl() {

//define curl command and execute
    def proc = "curl fakecommand".execute()

// cURL uses error output stream for progress output.
    Thread.start { System.err << proc.err } 
// Wait until cURL process finished
    proc.waitFor()
 }


}

return new GroovyClass();
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
if (run) {
   def groovyClass= load 'test.groovy'
   groovyClass.executeCurl()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Jenkinsfile you may only use objects of classes which implement the serializable interface.

If this is not the case sometimes you get an error message, sometimes it works by chance and sometimes it seems that just nothing happened.

In case you want to use objects of a non-serializable type you need to encapsulate this in a method which is annotated with `@NonCPS`. In addition to that when creating a process this would mean that you need to disable the sandbox mode.

However this is not what you want. Because this would execute curl on the master in a flyweight executor which should not do any such tasks.

For executing something in pipeline on a node you have to use either the `bat` or the `sh` step.

Be sure to check the [Jenkins Pipeline tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) and the steps reference and snippet generator. File access works differently as well.

You may of course also call the groovy binary to run a script from within pipeline using `bat` or `sh`